# localizing numeric value in DevExpress report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am creating a XtraReport for my application. It has some numerical fields.

My PC has format culture as en-us. But I want french culture to be used in the report as format culture. So, I have modified the current thread culture to french before generating the report. It correctly format my DateTime fields in the report since I give edit mask for those fields.

With out edit mask numerical fields are not formatted. It shows period(.) as decimal separator, not comma(,). When I give edit mask to the numeric fields it correctly shows decimal separator comma(,).

My problem here is, if I give edit mask to the fields it shows unwanted decimal values. For eg: if I use indian culture, it shows 2 decimal places even though the original value has no decimal values (It shows 433.00 instead of showing 433). Because of this problem I didn't give Edit Mask for the numerical fields.

I just want to use the decimal separator of the current thread to display numerical fields in the report, not for showing the default decimal values. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1498)

Comment: Fares: If i add EditMask in the above table, it also formatted the decimal values based on culture. I just want to use decimal separator from culture.